# Search in range of dates for current date

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date, range

After clicking a button, I want to check if the current date is in a range of cells.
If present, the loop should end and nothing should happen.
If not present, insert the date into the next empty cell in that range.

I tried a "For each" method but it checks every date in the range and gives a response for every cell.
I only want to know if it is already present and not a response for every cell that is not the current date.

```vb
Private Function DateUpdateWithCheck()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim searchrange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    myDate = Date

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("History")
    ws.Activate

    Set searchrange = ws.Range("CA1:CC1")

    For Each cell In searchrange
        If cell.Value = myDate Then
            MsgBox ("Date already in it. End the loop")
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox ("Date is not in it. Insert Date.")
            GoTo yesinsert
        End If
    Next


yesinsert:

    With ws
        lRow = Range("C1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
    
        ActiveCell.Value = Date
        'ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Copy
        'ActiveCell.EntireColumn.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: `if IsError(Application.Match(inquiryDate, dateRange, 0))=False Then` will check if there's an error trying to match in the `dateRange` for your `inquiryDate`.  Use this catch for an error that would occur when you cannot match to determine next steps.  If an error is not caught, then you have a match; if there is an error, you do not have a match.

Comment: The thing is, i am not getting an error because there are already dates in the range. But the dates differ from today. I am getting multiple "Date is not in it. Insert Date" Messages for every old date and at the end i am getting the "Date already in it. End the loop" Message

Comment: @Ardor The thing is you did not try what Cyril said. You loop through every cell and that is something different that doing a `Application.Match`. So if you try what Cyil said you will see that this is the solution to the issue.

Comment: Ah okay, i am gonna try that out first then.

Comment: I tried it out and thats the outcome. I am still getting multiple messages for each cell in the range. Either i used the method wrong somehow (which could certainly be) or it wasnt the solution yet.
`For Each cell In searchrange

If IsError(Application.Match(myDate, searchrange, 0)) = False Then

MsgBox ("Date already in it. End the loop")
Exit For

Else
MsgBox ("Date is not in it. Insert Date.")

'GoTo yesinsert

End If
Next `
Thats what i changed. As already said. Totally new to it and cant tell were the error lies.

Comment: How did you name your sheet `History`?  That should be a reserved name.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook how is that a reserved name? I can name it "History" too. Maybe version and/or localization dependent?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook there is no problem with getting the range. So it gets the right sheet and range already. There only is something with the For-each/if statements thats shouldnt be right

Comment: Must be.  I try to manually name a sheet History and it gives me "History is a reserved name." on 365 for Enterprise (Build 15629.20156).  Found this on it:  [EXCEL HISTORY IS A 'RESERVED NAME' HELP!](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-history-is-a-reserved-name-help/f8a398a4-b72c-48e3-82da-4f132c305e91#:~:text=Excel%20creates%20a%20sheet%20named%20History%20to%20track,%28with%20a%20space%20after%20the%20word%20History%29%20instead.)  Forgot to say... UK location.

Comment: @Ardor please check out the anwser from cyril below. You don't need a loop at all.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook On a German Excel 2019 it's not reserved. How weird that MS uses such a name instead of something that users are not going to choose as a name. I bet this gets messed up if you create it in 2019 and then open it up in 365 where it is a reserved name. What a bad design desicion by MS once again.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ having just opened up an old spreadsheet with "History" as my sheet name, running 365, I get no error message when opening.  If i try to change the sheet name, I get no error moving away from "History".  If I try and change a sheet name to "History" i get the error message that it's reserved, in both VBA and from the instance... weird indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Will further explain my comment with an example.

First thing:  You're using a `private function` and not having any input... a `function` will not act upon cells; it only outputs a value.  You want to use a `Subroutine` to perform actions on cells.

Second bit:  In your current code, you are checking each cell, and in each scenario that you check  `If cell.Value = myDate Then`, you kick out your msgbox... if you have a long date list, that's a lot.  You could resolve this by adding in check values and only doing the msgbox after the entire loop has been checked.

Alternatively, you could not do a loop at all and use `Application.Match()`, such that (untested):

```
Sub DateChecked()
    dim inquiryDate as date:  inquiryDate = ActiveCell.Value
    dim ws as worksheet:  set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("History")
    dim dateRange as range:  set dateRange = ws.Range("CA1:CC1")
    if IsError(Application.Match(inquiryDate, dateRange, 0))=True then
        'Do something when you have no match
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the visualization. But i tried it out and i am getting the "Do something when you have no match" result, for both situations. So if it is already in the range and if its not in the range.

Comment: @Ardor an `if` statement has an inherent check when the condition is true; if you want to do something when the condition is not met, you need an `Else`.  I had inserted that comment so you could fill in as needed, where the main point of the example is not using the loop at all (I saw from your comment to the main thread that you tried to insert the line to your loop).

Comment: And make sure your dates in the range are actual numeric dates and not text looking like dates.

Comment: Thtats what i changed after your answer. I already removed the for-each method but i am getting the first msgbox on both occasions. Even though there is an else for another case.  `If IsError(Application.Match(myDate, searchrange, 0)) = True Then

MsgBox ("Date already in it. End the loop")

Else
MsgBox ("Date is not in it. Insert Date.")

'GoTo yesinsert

End If `

Comment: They are dates.

Comment: @Ardor Did you use `IsDate()` to verify?  I recognize you stated that they are dates, so wanted to check how you verified.  Additionally, making sure the `searchRange` is also full of dates (year, month, & day) is worthwhile.

Comment: I checked the formatting in the excel file. Formatting looks like this 10.10.2022  dd.mm.yyyy. I can be sure that they are dates, because i was able to check it useing the foreach from before. I did get the the true or false depending on the cell. Atleast in the 3 cells that i am trying out atm, i can be 100% sure that they are dates.

Comment: Did youch set the `inquiryDate` to the date you are looking for? For today `inquiryDate = Date`

Comment: @Cyril I used instead of `inquiryDate = ActiveCell.Value =>  inquiryDate = date` to get the date from today, hope thats okay

Comment: @Pᴇʜ same thought there

Comment: Try `Application.Match(cDbl(inquiryDate), dateRange, 0)` instead.

Comment: Also i am using it in a private function to call it when needed and to insert it as an extra method. I am calling the function in a sub though

Comment: @Ardor then the only other thing I can think to check is your `searchRange`, which is currently three cells:  CA1, CB1, CC1... do you want this to be a dynamic range, rather than fixed, considering you're adding to the list?

Comment: @Ardor you can call another subroutine from a subroutine; the issue with the function is that it can only output a value, not make a change, so `ActiveCell.Value = Date` shouldn't be possible.

Comment: The cDbl solved it. Only had to change the True into False afterwards though.  But how do i change it into a dynamic one? Would be helpful aswell

Comment: @Ardor assuming `cells(1, "CA")` is always your start, `dim searchRange as range:  set searchRange = Range(Cells(1, "CA"), Cells(1, "CA").End(xltoRight))` should do it.

Comment: @Ardor if this answer aided in resolving your issue, please mark as answered.

Comment: I will, thank you both very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Thats the full answer code to my question for future reference.

```
Sub HistoryUpdate()

DateUpdateWithCheck

End Sub

Private Function DateUpdateWithCheck()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim myDate As Date
Dim searchrange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lRow As Long


myDate = Date

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("History")
ws.Activate

Set searchrange = ws.Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(1, "C").End(xlToRight))


If IsError(Application.Match(CDbl(myDate), searchrange, 0)) = True Then

With ws
    lRow = Range("C1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
    
    ActiveCell.Value = Date
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Copy
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    
End With

End If

End Function
```